# For-loop error when dividing an array

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I created a for-loop trying to divide all my "Signed" or "Signed LOI" opportunities to a array called **"SignedArray"**. Then I want to grab the 9 most recent "Signed" opportunities to another array called **"NineRecentOpportunities"**.

***The error message:***

[image]

**My JS Code:**

```
export function MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet, Opportunities){

    let SignedArray;

    // Sets the 9 most recent "Signed" opportunities to the array.
    let index = 0;
    for (let k = 0; k < Opportunities.length; k++) {

        if(Opportunities[k].StageName === ("Signed" || "Signed LOI") ){

            SignedArray[index] = Opportunities[k];

            index++;
            
        }

    }
    let NineRecentOpportunities = SignedArray.slice(-9)
```

**Refined Question:**

My goal is to get the 9 most recent "Signed" or "Signed LOI" opportunities to an array.
Is there a better way to go about this? Would my way work to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let SignedArray;
```

You never initialized the variable, so it is "undefined", hence your error. Also, your if statement won't work. When you want to compare one field to several values, you need to repeat the field each time:

```
if(record.StageName === 'Signed' || record.StageName === 'Signed LOI') {
```

But we can actually make it more efficient to read by extracting that out to an Array or Set we can check. Your code would end up looking more like this:

```
let validStages = ['Signed', 'Signed LOI'];
let NineRecentOpportunities = Opportunities.filter(
  (record) => validStages.indexOf(record.StageName) > -1
).slice(-9);
```

Here, we use an Array to define the stages we want to look for, then use filter to easily find those records. Array.prototype.filter always returns an Array, so we can chain directly to using slice from there.

And if we decide to use a Set:

```
let validStages = new Set(['Signed', 'Signed LOI']);
let NineRecentOpportunities = Opportunities.filter(
  (record) => validStages.has(record.StageName)
).slice(-9);
```

Keywords you'll want to look for on the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/):

- Array.indexOf
- Array.filter
- Arrow functions

Realistically, you should take a moment to just familiarize yourself with all the Array functions, they're really useful.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me! I need to do more research on arrays in Javascript.